# How to make makefile execute after build

Tags: c++, makefile

```
CPP=g++
CPPFLAGS=-Iincludes
SOURCEDIR=code
SOURCES=$(shell ls $(SOURCEDIR))
OBJECTDIR=obj
BINDIR=bin
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
EXECUTABLE=bin/assignment1

%.o: $(SOURCEDIR)/%.cpp
    if [ ! -d $(OBJECTDIR) ]; then mkdir $(OBJECTDIR); fi; $(CPP) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $< -o $(OBJECTDIR)/$@

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    if [ ! -d $(BINDIR) ]; then mkdir $(BINDIR); fi; $(CPP) $(addprefix $(OBJECTDIR)/,$(OBJECTS)) -o $@

clean:
    if [ -d $(BINDIR) ]; then rm -rfv $(BINDIR); fi; if [ -d $(OBJECTDIR) ]; then rm -rfv $(OBJECTDIR); fi;

all: $(EXECUTABLE)
```

Right now i have my header in includes, my main in code folder. I want it so that when i run make it rungs the program after it compiles it to bin/assignment1 how do i do that?

Comment: Also how can i make it ignore warnings?

Comment: Don't IGNORE warnings. Fix your warnings!

Comment: Its a small warning i cant fix changing an int to a null

Comment: Actually just went ahead and fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

If you add a few lines to your makefile, you can make it run your code:

```
CPP=g++
CPPFLAGS=-Iincludes
SOURCEDIR=code
SOURCES=$(shell ls $(SOURCEDIR))
OBJECTDIR=obj
BINDIR=bin
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
EXECUTABLE=bin/assignment1

all: $(EXECUTABLE) run

%.o: $(SOURCEDIR)/%.cpp
    if [ ! -d $(OBJECTDIR) ]; then mkdir $(OBJECTDIR); fi; $(CPP) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $< -o $(OBJECTDIR)/$@

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    if [ ! -d $(BINDIR) ]; then mkdir $(BINDIR); fi; $(CPP) $(addprefix $(OBJECTDIR)/,$(OBJECTS)) -o $@

.PHONY : clean
clean:
    if [ -d $(BINDIR) ]; then rm -rfv $(BINDIR); fi; if [ -d $(OBJECTDIR) ]; then rm -rfv $(OBJECTDIR); fi;

.PHONY : run
run: $(EXECUTABLE)
    $(EXECUTABLE) arg1 arg2
```

I moved your "all" target to the top - that way, if you type "make", it will do "make all" by default. I also added a "run" target, and ".PHONY" on the `clean` and `run` target, as they don't actually "make" anything.

Answer (score 2):

You only need to add another target and add it to your *all* dependencies list so you could have:

```
all: $(EXECUTABLE) run

run:
     bin/assignment1/main
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be as simple as replacing your current `all` target with

```
all: execute

execute: $(EXECUTABLE)
    $(EXECUTABLE)   # This works because you have a well qualified path
                    # If $(EXECUTABLE) was a bare name you would need 
                    # to use ./$(EXECUTABLE)

.PHONY: execute clean
```

though you should put the `all` target as the first target in the makefile if you want it to be built when you simply type `make`; if you don't your makefile will build the executable on a unmodified `make`, but only also run it if you use `make all`.

Comment: Yah. That would be spaces instead of a tab in from of the action line. Comes from typing into the editor instead of typing in emacs and then copy-n-psting.